# Fetch Ccc form mails with php Imap

Tags: php, imap

I have been trying to fetch Collaborators from received emails via **php imap**

```
imap_fetch_overview($stream, $email_id, 0);

$from = $this->decode_imap_text($overview[0]->from);
$subject = $this->decode_imap_text($overview[0]->subject);
$to = $this->decode_imap_text($overview[0]->to);



function decode_imap_text($str) {
    $result = '';
    $decode_header = imap_mime_header_decode($str);
    foreach ($decode_header AS $obj) {
        $result .= htmlspecialchars(rtrim($obj->text, "\t"));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

but can't find how to fetch CCC or collaborators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `imap_fetch_overview` you can't get CC addresses, you'll need [`imap_fetchheader`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchheader.php) or [`imap_headerinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headerinfo.php) for that.